# Excess baggage of 15 kilos with Qatar Airways to the Philippines

Tags: luggage, filipino-citizens

My baggage allowance with Qatar Airways to the Philippines is 40 kilogrammes. I have 55 kg, is that OK?

Comment: Seriously? The word *excess* means *too much*. So, guess what? Exceeding by 15kg is too much. As a matter, it is 15kg too much!

Comment: What is your cabin class?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: To answer your question, no. That is not ok.

According to [Qatar Airways](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/baggage.page), if you are in first class, you are allowed a bag up to 50kg. If you are in business class, then it is 40kg, Lastly, if you are in the economy class, it is 30kg. Otherwise you will [need to pay](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/excess-baggage-rates.page) extra per 1 kg.

Comment: Worth mentioning, from your link: `•A single piece of checked baggage must not weigh more than 32kg (70lb). Any bags weighing more than 32kg (70lb) must be broken down such that each piece weighs less than 32kg (70lb).`. Bags are loaded and unloaded by hand, so a bag that weights too much may get refused even if it is less than your total allowance.